# Grok Pattern not working in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

After parsing logs I am find there are some new lines at the end of the message

Sample message

> ts:2016-04-26 05-02-16-018
>   CDT|ll:TRACE|tid:10000.140|scf:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pc|mn:null|fn:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|ln:749|auid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|eid:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-58261618-1-1461664935955-139|cid:900009865|ml:null|mid:-99|uip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|hip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|pli:null|msg:
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|pl: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> TAKE 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I am using the regex pattern below as suggested below as answers

ts:(?(([0-9]+)-*)+ ([0-9]+-*)+ [A-Z]+)\|ll:%{WORD:ll}\|tid:%{NUMBER:tid}\|scf:%{DATA:scf}\|mn:%{WORD:mn}\|fn:%{WORD:fn}\|ln:%{WORD:ln}\|auid:%{WORD:auid}\|eid:%{DATA:eid}\|cid:%{WORD:cid}\|ml:%{WORD:ml}\|mid:%{NUMBER:mid}\|uip:%{DATA:uip}\|hip:%{DATA:hip}\|pli:%{WORD:pli}\|\s*msg:%{GREEDYDATA:msg}(\|pl:(?(.|\r|\n)*))

But unfortunately it is not working properly when the last part of the log is not present

> ts:2016-04-26 05-02-16-018
>   CDT|ll:TRACE|tid:10000.140|scf:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pc|mn:null|fn:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|ln:749|auid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|eid:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-58261618-1-1461664935955-139|cid:900009865|ml:null|mid:-99|uip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|hip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

What should be the correct pattern?

-------------------Previous Question --------------------------------------

I am trying to parse log line such as this one.

ts:2016-04-26 05-02-16-018 CDT|ll:TRACE|tid:10000.140|scf:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pc|mn:null|fn:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|ln:749|auid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|eid:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-58261618-1-1461664935955-139|cid:900009865|ml:null|mid:-99|uip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|hip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|pli:null|msg: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Below is my logstash filter

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => ["mesage", "ts:(?<date>(([0-9]+)-*)+ ([0-9]+-*)+ [A-Z]+)\|ll:%{WORD:ll}\|tid:%{WORD:tid}\|scf:%{WORD:scf}\|mn:%{WORD:mn}\|fn:%{WORD:fn}\|ln:%{WORD:ln}\|auid:%{WORD:auid}\|eid:%{WORD:eid}\|cid:%{WORD:cid}\|ml:%{WORD:ml}\|mid:%{WORD:mid}\|uip:%{WORD:uip}\|hip:%{WORD:hip}\|pli:%{WORD:pli}\|msg:%{WORD:msg}"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["ts","yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-SSS ZZZ"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
```

I am getting "_grokparsefailure"

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the configuration from @HAL, there was a few things to change:

- In the grok filter `mesage` => `message`
- In the date filter `ts` => `date` so the date parsing is on the right field
- The `CDT` is a time zone name, it is captured by `z` in the date syntax.

So the right configuration would look like this :

```
filter{
    grok {
        match => ["message", "ts:(?<date>(([0-9]+)-*)+ ([0-9]+-*)+ [A-Z]+)\|ll:%{WORD:ll}\|tid:%{NUMBER:tid}\|scf:%{DATA:scf}\|mn:%{WORD:mn}\|fn:%{WORD:fn}\|ln:%{WORD:ln}\|auid:%{WORD:auid}\|eid:%{DATA:eid}\|cid:%{WORD:cid}\|ml:%{WORD:ml}\|mid:%{NUMBER:mid}\|uip:%{DATA:uip}\|hip:%{DATA:hip}\|pli:%{WORD:pli}\|\s*msg:%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["date","yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-SSS z"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot baudsp

Answer (score 0):

Tried to parse your input via grokdebug with your expression but it failed to read out any fields. Managed to get it to work by changing the expression to:

```
ts:(?<date>(([0-9]+)-*)+ ([0-9]+-*)+ [A-Z]+)\|ll:%{WORD:ll}\|tid:%{NUMBER:tid}\|scf:%{DATA:scf}\|mn:%{WORD:mn}\|fn:%{WORD:fn}\|ln:%{WORD:ln}\|auid:%{WORD:auid}\|eid:%{DATA:eid}\|cid:%{WORD:cid}\|ml:%{WORD:ml}\|mid:%{NUMBER:mid}\|uip:%{DATA:uip}\|hip:%{DATA:hip}\|pli:%{WORD:pli}\|\s*msg:%{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

I also think that you need to change the name of the column that logstash shall parse from `mesage` to `message`.

Also, the date parsing pattern should match the format of the date in the input. There is no timezone identity (`ZZZ`) in your input data (at least not in the example).

Something like this should work better (not tested though):

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => ["mesage", "ts:(?<date>(([0-9]+)-*)+ ([0-9]+-*)+ [A-Z]+)\|ll:%{WORD:ll}\|tid:%{NUMBER:tid}\|scf:%{DATA:scf}\|mn:%{WORD:mn}\|fn:%{WORD:fn}\|ln:%{WORD:ln}\|auid:%{WORD:auid}\|eid:%{DATA:eid}\|cid:%{WORD:cid}\|ml:%{WORD:ml}\|mid:%{NUMBER:mid}\|uip:%{DATA:uip}\|hip:%{DATA:hip}\|pli:%{WORD:pli}\|\s*msg:%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["ts","yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-SSS"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
```

}

Comment: There is a few mistakes in your configuration, see my answer